# Electrostatic arc safety

Tags: safety, uv, static-electricity

I'm experimenting with early electrostatic devices, and I'm measuring spark gap length to determine voltages generated. How dangerous is it to observe these arcs with the naked eye? Should I wear something like welding goggles?

Does anyone have information about the relative dangers of different kinds of arc vs duration of observation and distance from the source? I imagine that something that would handle a welding arc wouldn't have a problem with a Leyden jar spark but I have no way to know how a high voltage low power spark compares.

Comment: Start with safety glasses.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on many things, radiation reduces depending on distance so how far you are helps, how long you plan to events and if you want to stare at them directly.

if you are far enough, it could be okay, but you have to err in the side of safety in these cases... so get proper eye protection.